# Closure of the set of functions with respect to the $\infty$-norm

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I want to show that the set of functions $X=\{f\in C[0,1]:f(0)=0\}$ is closed with respect to the $\infty$-norm.

Suppose $(f_n)\subset X$ is a convergent sequence, now I need to find some function $f\in X$ such that
$$
|| f_n-f||_\infty\to0
$$
How do I do that?

Comment: By closed set I mean a set containing all its limit points, so if I have a sequence in $X$, I need to show that there is a limit of this sequence which belongs to $X$.

Comment: sorry, I somehow automatically assumed convergence, I'll edit the question.

Comment: You know $(f_n)$ converges to some $f\in C[0,1]$. You need to show that $f$ is, in fact, in $X$. So, you need to show that $f(0)=0$. But if $\Vert f_n-f\Vert\rightarrow 0$, then in particular $| f_n(0)-f(0)| =| f(0)|\rightarrow 0$. So ...

Comment: Of course, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re trying to go about it the hard way: to show that $X$ is closed, just show that $C[0,1]\setminus X$ is open. In other words, show that if $f\in C[0,1]$ and $f(x)\ne 0$, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $g(0)\ne 0$ whenever $\|f-g\|_\infty<\epsilon$. A satisfactory $\epsilon$ is easily specified in terms of $f(0)$.